# luatexja introduces huge white space after right single quotation mark (code point 8217)

Tags: luatexja

I am having an issue with `luatexja` where it introduces huge white space after RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (8217).

[image]

MWE here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[match]{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage[noto-otf]{luatexja-preset}

\begin{document}
That’s it. The ``’'' is \textsc{right single quotation mark}, code point 8217.
\end{document}
```

Is there some setting that I can use to avoid this?

Comment: There are two possible quick fixes I see:  Instruct `LuaLaTeX` to “step back”, as it were (using `’\!`) or use `'` (Apostrophe, ASCII 39) to begin with. Both are not ideal, and I am sure there are other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The char is classified by luatexja as a JAchar, a characters which is used in Japanese typesetting and so has special settings for this. You can change this classification (see the documentation), or print it once as ALchar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[match]{luatexja-fontspec}
%\usepackage[noto-otf]{luatexja-preset}

\begin{document}
That’s That\ltjalchar`’s it. 

The ``’''  The ``\ltjalchar`’'' 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As said by Ulrike Fischer, it is due to the General Block (Block 9, in luatexja language) to be considered as JAchar. You can reverse this with `\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-9}}` but, presumably, it will mess up your typography when you use these characters in CJK text. I guess you should switch back with `\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={+9}}` before such text.

Also, the commande setting all charactes but CJK charaters to ALchar is `\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, +6, +7, -8, -9}}`